# CorePlot plot view in NSTableView animates badly upon collapse/expansion

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, core-plot, nstableview, appkit

I have implemented a calendar view ([GitHub](https://github.com/DivineDominion/CCLCalendarView)). When you click on a day cell, a `NSTableViewRow` is inserted below, containing details for the day.

Insertion and deletion is animated as `NSTableViewAnimationSlideDown` and `NSTableViewAnimationSlideUp` respectively. The standard AppKit components seem to simply vanish during the animation. That was weird enough for a few test labels, but Core Plot and it's `CPTGraphHostingView`s don't play along nicely:

The plot view (containing 1 bar plot) appears outside the visible range of the row view and jumps into place once the row finished its animation. See animated GIF below:

[image: Collapsind/Expanding]

The row view contains a custom view with 2 labels and 1 plot view. The custom view is pinned to all 4 edges of to the row view via AutoLayout (in code). I added Auto Layout constraints to the plot and labels relative to the edges of the parent custom view. I had hoped this would resize the plot according to the animation, but it doesn't seem to resize but *move* instead (slide not shrink).

**How can I stick the plot view to the row's bottom during animation and clip it while the row slides?**

1. Ordering the plot behind the rest of the table seems to be my first problem here.
2. I have no clue why the plot, drawing above the rest or not, doesn't slide animated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was an issue with Core Plot being based on `CALayer`s, which don't animate well in a solely view-based table. After fiddling with different ideas for a while, I got it working with `setWantsLayer:YES`, sent to the container view (not the `NSTableView`! That didn't work out well).

This can be done in Interface Builder easily:

[image: setWantsLayer in IB]